# Result of socket.io request in IE 9 is Pending

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am running node.js/socket.io server.

I am testing with IE 9.

When I open dev tool in IE 9, many of the socket.io request are displaying their result as **"Pending.."**. Although I see they have returned the result which I want.

I am not sure if this default behavior or a bad thing which might cause my browser slow.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: IE 9 Dev tool network capture]

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing long polling as your socket transport (xhr, jsonp, etc...) having pending http requests is expected. The socket client should open an http GET to the server and the server should keep it open until there is data for the socket or the http interval expires. When either of those cases happen the client re-opens a GET and starts listening again. So in practice there should always be one pending http request. That said I see that there are multiple in your screenshot. I'm curious if its a tools issue. Have you tried your test above in chrome or firefox? Do you get the same result? Is socket communication working as expected apart from what's being displayed there?